# Wordpress: ajax_url is not defined

Tags: wordpress

Hi I'm a beginner to `wordpress` and I'm currently facing problems in sending data from front-side to server via ajax.
I want to send my select option value (#sheetList) to server. To check if the value is correctly delivered I want to receive "alert" as response.

I have placed my js code in `ajaxRequest.js` and added localizing script in `functions.php`. 
But I am still getting this error:

```html
Uncaught ReferenceError: my_ajax_object is not defined
```

Anyone knows how to fix this problem?
Here are my codes:

js

```js
jQuery(function($input) {
 $('#sheetList').on('change', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: my_ajax_object.ajax_url,
   data: {
    action: 'data_custom_ajax',
    data: $('#sheetList').val()
   },
   success: function(data) {
    alert(response);
   }
  })
 });
 
});
```

functions.php

```js
/** AJAX Request script */

function my_enqueue() {
 wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/my-ajax-script.js',
  array('jquery'));
 wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'my_ajax_object',
  array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php')));
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue');

function data_custom_ajax() {
 $custom_val = $_POST['text'];

 echo json_encode(array("data_result"=> $custom_val));
 die;
}

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_data_custom_ajax', 'data_custom_ajax');
add_action('wp_ajax_data_custom_ajax', 'data_custom_ajax');
```

Comment: Try to open the page source and search for <script id="ajax-script" and check if the source file that is loaded. Also, I'd suggest you to prefix all the functions to make sure names are unique. Same for the scripts handles: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

Comment: oh my gosh you saved my life! I forgot to include get_header() on my page template. That's why ajax-script wasn't loading.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow!
You're including `my-ajax-script.js` file in your `functions.php` file but you said that your JS script is placed in `ajaxRequest.js` file.

Also make sure that your js codes are included at all. You can test it by placing an alert or a `console.log('SOMETHING');` at the top of file.